# Register multiple fields 1 at a time

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I need to insert a "line" at a time from a table, as in:

[image]

I will complete this form and register the same in the bank. But I need to be registered one line at a time. For example: (Monday, 08:30, 16:30, 30), after: (Tuesday, 08:30, 16:30, 30)

Controller:

```
public string Register(TimeGrid timeGrid)
{
    {
        if (timeGrid != null)
        {
            using (TimeGridContext contextObj = new TimeGridContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    contextObj.workload.Add(timeGrid);
                    contextObj.SaveChanges();
                    return "Registro adicionado com sucesso";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "Registro inválido";
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
   public class TimeGrid
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }

    public string NameDayofWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Html:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Domingo</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="domingo" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

   <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Segunda-feira</label></div>
     <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="segunda-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.MondayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Terça-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="terca-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.TuesdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Quarta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="quarta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.WednesdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Quinta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="quinta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.ThursdayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Sexta-feira</label></div>
    <input type="hidden" ng-true-value="sexta-feira" />
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayIn" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayOut" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.timeGrid.FridayInterval" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"><label>Sábado</label></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" /></div>
    <div class="col"><input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar" ng-click="timeGrid(timeGridForm)">
  </div>
</form>
```

Below the controller angularJS and the service that communicates with my api

```
  $scope.timeGrid = function () {
    result = $scope;
    traineeControlService.timeGrid(result.vm)
        .then(function () {

            alert("Teste 1");
        }, function () {
            alert('Erro ao tentar adicionar o livro');
        });
}


   myApp.service("traineeControlService", function ($http) {
    this.timeGrid = function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "Register",
        data: JSON.stringify(result),
        dataType: "json"
    });
    return response;
    }
  }
```

Comment: That looks like Angular syntax in your markup, doesn't it support two way binding and on an event shouldn't the model simply be updated?

Comment: Yes, I am using angular to integrate the front end with the back end.

Comment: Can you post code for timeGrid(timeGridForm)?

Comment: @Gvr Can you isolate where the issue is, in Angular you click a button it generates a new line and fires an event, you edit a line it also fires an event.